# Can you specify state properties in the react hooks invalidation list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const foo = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.foo);

useEffect(() => {
   // ...
}, [foo.name, foo.title]);
```

Can you specify properties of something returned by useSelector, or should I just put foo itself in the invalidation list for useEffect here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just fine. The only real requirement for what's in a dependency array is that each value is stateful or a prop passed down from a parent component - so, go ahead and use `[foo.name, foo.title]`. (Using `[foo]` instead might capture more changes than you're expecting, because that'll run the effect whenever anything in `foo` changes, and not just the name or title)